# How to store string array using SharedPreference?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

I want to save two string values on checking toggle button and retrieve it from another `Fragment`. This is what I did to the button `OnClickListener` but it isn't working:

```
holder.favButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton favButton, boolean isChecked){
        if (isChecked)
            favButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(favButton.getContext(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString("PRODUCT_APP", "Product_Favorite").commit();

        else
            favButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(favButton.getContext(), R.mipmap.ic_cart));
    }
});
```

This is my `SharedPreference` class

```
public class SharedPreference {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PRODUCT_APP";
    public static final String FAVORITES = "Product_Favorite";

    public SharedPreference() {
        super();
    }

    // This four methods are used for maintaining favorites.
    public void saveFavorites(Context context, List<CardItemModel> favorites) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);

        editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);

        editor.commit();
    }

    public void addFavorite(Context context, CardItemModel product) {
        List<CardItemModel> favorites = getFavorites(context);
        if (favorites == null)
            favorites = new ArrayList<CardItemModel>();
        favorites.add(product);
        saveFavorites(context, favorites);
    }

    public void removeFavorite(Context context, CardItemModel product) {
        ArrayList<CardItemModel> favorites = getFavorites(context);
        if (favorites != null) {
            favorites.remove(product);
            saveFavorites(context, favorites);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<CardItemModel> getFavorites(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        List<CardItemModel> favorites;

        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (settings.contains(FAVORITES)) {
            String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(FAVORITES, null);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            CardItemModel[] favoriteItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites,
                    CardItemModel[].class);

            favorites = Arrays.asList(favoriteItems);
            favorites = new ArrayList<CardItemModel>(favorites);
        } else
            return null;

        return (ArrayList<CardItemModel>) favorites;
    }
}
```

Comment: This link can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences

Comment: Your `setOnCheckedChangeListener` should not work. There's no if corresponding the last else part. Please fix your code first and then post the code again. It should give you a compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

let's solve this ^^.
**You can save multiple favorites** in a single preference by adding numerous favorites in a single string, each favorite item separated by comma. Then you can use `convertStringToArray` method to convert it into String Array. Here is the full source code.
Use MyUtility Methods to save multiple favorite items.

```
  MyUtility.addFavoriteItem(this, "Sports");
        MyUtility.addFavoriteItem(this, "Entertainment");
```

get String array of all favorites saved

```
String[] favorites = MyUtility.getFavoriteList(this);// returns {"Sports","Entertainment"};
```

Save these methods in separate Utility class

```
public abstract class MyUtility {

public static boolean addFavoriteItem(Activity activity,String favoriteItem){
    //Get previous favorite items
    String favoriteList = getStringFromPreferences(activity,null,"favorites");
    // Append new Favorite item
    if(favoriteList!=null){
        favoriteList = favoriteList+","+favoriteItem;
    }else{
        favoriteList = favoriteItem;
    }
    // Save in Shared Preferences
    return putStringInPreferences(activity,favoriteList,"favorites");
}
public static String[] getFavoriteList(Activity activity){
    String favoriteList = getStringFromPreferences(activity,null,"favorites");
    return convertStringToArray(favoriteList);
}
private static boolean putStringInPreferences(Activity activity,String nick,String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = activity.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, nick);
    editor.commit();                        
    return true;        
}
private static String getStringFromPreferences(Activity activity,String defaultValue,String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = activity.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String temp = sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
    return temp;        
}

private static String[] convertStringToArray(String str){
    String[] arr = str.split(",");
    return arr;
}
```

}

If you have to add extra favorites. Then get favorite string from `SharedPreference` and append comma+favorite item and save it back into `SharedPreference`.
* You can use any other string for separator instead of comma.